# Sending Email Report in Automation Testing Project

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I had coded an automation testing project using Selenium.

I want to send email with attachment of report to stakeholder.
I had tried many email services like sendgrid but it's cannot support sending email with attachment.

May I know which library or service provide this functionalities?

I know my questions is not related to technical but i really need recommendation. Please don't close my thread.

Please help me. A billion thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this can help you , this is JavaScript code , I tested , can work

```js
/*
Step 1. 初始化專案
npm init -y 
Step 2. 安裝套件
npm i nodemailer 
*/


const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 465,
  auth: {
    user: 'my@gmail.com',//  your mail
    pass: 'token',//this is google accout can set a token inside
  },
});

transporter.sendMail({             
  from: 'my@gmail.com',     //from your mail send to target mail
  to: 'target@gmail.com',
  subject: 'test',
  html: '測試送信',
}).then(info => {
  console.log({ info });
}).catch(console.error);
```